# Call Simple method from Webmethod using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I am calling a webmethod from an aspx page. The webmethod is in code behind only. Now, I want to know if it is possible to call a method from the webmethod?

For example:

```
//Simple Method
Public static void BindData()
{
   // Bind DataList using DataTable
}

[WebMethod]
Public static void InsertData()
{
   // Call BindData()
}
```

Here, I am getting error for `DataList` control as it must use static type. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access controls in static methods. Your webform is a class and controls are properties of this class and they are non-static so you cannot access non-static properties in static method. You can use ajax to populate datalist.

Comment: So, the solution is...? =)

Comment: That was a leading question. I know the various solutions but for this to be an actual **useful answer** you might want to include a working fix in your post. Just sayin'.